# Not able to display the data Using ajax?

Tags: jquery

Hi I am new to php and ajax I wrote an select query in php and pushed the results into an array and I am trying to display the results in the table format using ajax for that I had wrote an ajax call as follows

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"propage.php",
        dataType:"json",
        data:{
          action:"addFilter",
           pid:pid,
           
         },
        success : function(filres)
        { 
          
          if(filres.status==1)
          {
            { $.each(filres.data, function(i, row) { 
              var row = "<tr>"; 
              row += "<td>" + row.filter_id + "</td>"; 
              row += "<td>" + row.name + "</td>";
              row += "<td>" + row.filter + "</td>";
              row +="<td>"<a href=>Delete</a>"</td>";
              row += "</tr>"; 
              $("#table_filter").append(row); 
            }); 
          }
        }
          else
          {
            $("#get_msg").html("<p style=\'color:red;font-weight:bolder;\'>"+filres.data+"</p>");
          }
        }
    
      });
      return false;
    });
```

But in the table I am getting data as undefined but when I click on the button I am getting the data in the network tab as follows

```
data: [{filter_id: "1", name: "ss", filter: "SOCIAL SECURITY"},…]
```

Can anyone help me out for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function to do this.

The reason its not working is that  have some syntax error in your `td` item where you are using `a` element also you there are some extra brackets data as required to. Also you are using same var `row` to get data from `.each` and assign to your table as well.

Run snippet below to see it working.

```js
//Your data
let filres = {
  data: [{
    filter_id: "1",
    name: "ss",
    filter: "SOCIAL SECURITY"
  }]
}

//Foreach function
filres.data.forEach(function(item) {
  var row = "<tr>";
  row += "<td>" + item.filter_id + "</td>";
  row += "<td>" + item.name + "</td>";
  row += "<td>" + item.filter + "</td>";
  row += "<td><a href=>Delete</a></td>";
  row += "</tr>";
  $("#table_filter").append(row);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table_filter">

</div>
```

**Change your ajax** to this below all should work fine.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "propage.php",
  dataType: "json",
  data: {
    action: "addFilter",
    pid: pid,
  },
  success: function(filres) {
    if (filres.status == 1) {
        //Foreach function
          filres.data.forEach(function(item) {
            var row = "<tr>";
            row += "<td>" + item.filter_id + "</td>";
            row += "<td>" + item.name + "</td>";
            row += "<td>" + item.filter + "</td>";
            row += "<td><a href=>Delete</a></td>";
            row += "</tr>";
            $("#table_filter").append(row);
          })
       } else {
        $("#get_msg").html("<p style=\'color:red;font-weight:bolder;\'>" + filres.data + "</p>");
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: @G.Lakshmi Glad to hear that. Happy to help. Thanks.

Comment: hey cant I keep an id for the href element in the row @AlwaysHelping

Comment: @G.Lakshmi yes you can. Like this = `row +="<td><a href=" + item.filter_id +">Delete</a></td>"`

Comment: not filter id just an id on click I need to write another ajax call

Comment: I wrote like this             row += "<td><a id="open" href=>Delete</a></td>"; not working @AlwaysHelping

Comment: @G.Lakshmi Yeah you can do that. Once you `click` on it assign an `event` to that and do ajax call on that. I would if you want to post another question that will make things more clearer.

Comment: its just a small one I am trying keep an id for my anchor tag but its not working @AlwaysHelping please help me

Comment: @G.Lakshmi What id you want to keep. A dynamic one or just static id. Just assign whatever id you want to use and it should work. Sorry i am not catching you properly what you want to do with id and anchor tag.

Comment: row += "<td><a id="open" href=>Delete</a></td>"; I tried like this it is saying unexpected identifier I want to call an another ajax call for this onclick @AlwaysHelping

Comment: @G.Lakshmi Try this: `row += "<td><a id='open' href=''>Delete</a></td>";`

Comment: @G.Lakshmi Works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/h91gw7r4/ alert is showing when clicking on Delete with id='open'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218410/discussion-between-g-lakshmi-and-alwayshelping).

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the "row" on each iteration, so when you try to get the data it is no longer there, returning that "undefined". Try changing the "var row" to another variable name:

```
$.each(filres.data, function(i, row) { 
 var row = "<tr>" // <- Here;
```

Comment: I didnt understand what do you mean can I change the variable name @Symphonic